# Генерация кода для Windows 98 в Visual C++ 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Создаю в VS2010 проект Win32(+MFC). Сначала система ругалась что нет нужных библиотек. Я статически прилинковал MFC10 и MSVCR100.dll. Теперь при запуске выдает сообщение:
[image]

С какими опциями компилировать, чтобы exe-шка запускалась на Win 98 SE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собрать программу в VC98. Думаю, это единственное разумное решение. Ну, или хотя бы 2005-ю студию попробуйте.

Comment: В подтверждение: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213711/  ,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484511/   Это, несомненно, epic fail.